# Understanding proof method used to find limit of $(1 + \frac{2}{n})^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am using a textbook which provides many exercices and solutions in Calculus/Real Analysis at undergraduate level and I am currently practicing limits.

Here is the question: Find the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $(1 + \frac{2}{n})^n$

and the answer: $\forall n \geq1 : (1 + \frac{2}{n})^n = (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n  (1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}  ( \frac{n+1}{n+2}) \implies \lim=e^2$

I can't understand the method used by the author, i know there is probably other ways to find the answer but i realy want to understand this one.

Comment: $$...=\left(\left(1 + \frac{2}{n}\right)^{\frac n2}\right)^2$$

Comment: $\lim_n(1+1/n)^n=e$, so the product of the first two terms is $e^2$ and the third one will converge to one

Comment: What part of the method do you not understand? Do you not see why the equality between $(1+2/n)^n$ and the more complicated expression is true? Do you not see why the limit follows (the "$\implies$" step)? Or do you not see how the textbook thought to introduce the complicated expression in the equality?

Comment: Please add details about the method used by the author.  You give only the author's answer, but not their method.  If you are asking users here to do your work for you, because the solutions don't go step by step, that makes your question a problem statement question: "Here's the exercise, and here's the solution" ...  Doing so violates quality standards on this site.

Comment: @amWhy The author did not give any more information, which is why i am asking help on this site, the method the author used is exactly what i am trying to figure out as stated in the Title.

Comment: We can't answer your question, because as you know, the author didn't present the workings.  We can't know their method any more than you can.  You've mentioned no effort on your part, you haven't named the text, nor the author, and provided no other context.  In other words, you are hoping for any one of the seven, so far, answerers to do your work for you.

Comment: @skwirrL: You can accept one of the answers if it solves your puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

A-ha. I didn't understand what the author wanted to say until I looked into it for a long time!

Now that I understood, I'll tell you how to limit this method.

At first, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e$ is very well-known.

And, following holds... $$\left(1+\frac2n\right)^n=\left(\frac{n+2}n\right)^n=\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^n\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)$$
Then take a limit both side of equation, then you can get the limit is $e^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align} 
1+\frac{2}{n}&=\frac{n+2}{n}\\&=\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot \frac{n+2}{n+1}\\&=\left(1+\frac1n\right)\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)
\end{align}
$$

So $$
\begin{align} 
\left(1+\frac2n\right)^n&= \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^n\\
&= \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\cdot\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\cdot \frac1{1+\frac1{n+1}}
\end{align} $$

Then $$\frac1{1+\frac1{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{n+2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$  (\frac{n+2}{n})^n = ( \frac{n+1}{n})^n  (\frac{n+2}{n+1})^{n+1}  ( \frac{n+1}{n+2}) $$
Thus $$ (1 + \frac{2}{n})^n = (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n  (1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}  ( \frac{n+1}{n+2}) \implies lim=(e)(e)(1)=e^2$$

Answer (score 0):

You must follow the result $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\cfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=e$.
So $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\cfrac{2}{n}\right)^{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(\left(1+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{n}{2}}\right)^{\cfrac{n}{2}}\right)^{\cfrac{2}{n}}\right)^{n}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n}{n}}=e^{2}$

Answer (score 0):

I would let $2m = n$ and write
$$
\left(1 + \frac{2}{n}\right)^n = 
\left(1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)^{2m} =
\left( \left(1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)^{m}\right)^2
$$
and note taking the limit as $m \to \infty$ is the same as taking the limit as $n \to \infty$.

This will work when you replace $2$ by any other positive constant.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 2n\right)^n&=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{n\ln\left(1+\frac 2n\right)}\\
&=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+2/n)}{1/n}}
\end{align*}

Looking just at the limit now:

\begin{align*}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+2/n)}{1/n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{-2/n^2}{1+2/n}}{-1/n^2}&\text{by l'Hopital's rule: }\frac00\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{2}{1+2/n}}\\
&=2
\end{align*}

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 2n\right)^n&=e^2
\end{align*}